# Admin access issues Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking at creating a soloution on GCP, however the company I work for dosen't grant admin rights to PC's for everyone.

I am using a Windows 10 operating system.

Does anyone know if any GCP services require admin access, will I run into any hurdles with limited access?

Comment: GCP can be managed through your browser. You don't need any special permissions on your workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You **will** be able to access GCP services as long as you have a browser, **or** an RDP client for accessing Windows instances on GCP, **or** an SSH client for accessing Linux instances on GCP.

You **won't** be able to install the Cloud SDK locally, but the gcloud, gsutil, and bq command-line tools are available to you in your browser through the GCP Console.

*SSH Client Options:* MobaXterm has a portable client that will let you run SSH in a Linux like command line from Windows. If you can run their EXE file without admin rights on your PC, you are good to go. I believe Putty also has a portable client.